# Is it possible to completely ignore a catch block when debugging?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, exception, try-catch

I'm working within WinForms (.net 3.5), and have the following line of code:

```
     HitTestResult result;
     try
     {
        result = this.HitTest( e.X, e.Y, ChartElementType.DataPoint);
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
        //This happens, we don't care!
     }
```

I have no control over whether HitTest throws an exception, but if it does, I absolutely do not care.

Is it possible to disable my IDE from halting at this SPECIFIC catch block?  I understand I can disable the System.FormatException it may throw (from the Debug->Exceptions menu, but that's kind of overkill.

Thanks!

Comment: so this problem only bothers you when debugging your code?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but you can take off that "e" after "Exception" so VS don't tell you "e" is declared but not used :-D

Comment: Yes, during developement, this exception is sometimes thrown when the code gets executed before my window is painted, which is fine behavior.  This will cause my debugger to halt, because I have it set to halt on all thrown exceptions.  My hope is that there is some type of debugging attribute I can apply to avoid it from stopping.

Comment: So, your main gripe is you don't want it (under debug) to break on throw of this particular FormatException, but do want it to break when other throws for FormatException occur?

Comment: @James it sounds like that, and seems like a reasonable annoyance.

Comment: @James, yes, that it is what I want.  I'm not sure if this is even a practical request.  I want to wipe that catch off the face of the planet as far as the debugger is concerned.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [DebbugerStepThrough](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111965/Tips-on-Debugging-Using-DebuggerStepThrough-attrib) attribute to skip over that line. From MSDN:

> Instructs the debugger to step through the code instead of stepping
>   into the code.

For example:

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public void MyMethod()
{
    HitTestResult result;
    try
    {
        result = this.HitTest(e.X, e.Y, ChartElementType.DataPoint);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //This happens, we don't care!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you factor out your code into a separate method you can decorate it with [**`DebuggerStepThrough`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx) and the IDE will not halt:

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public void SomeMethod()
{
    HitTestResult result;
    try
    {
        result = this.HitTest(e.X, e.Y, ChartElementType.DataPoint);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //This happens, we don't care!
    }
}
```

Comment: we submitted at the same time :)

Comment: I think this may be the best solution, I'm about to test it out.

Answer (score 6):

You can place the try/catch block in its own method and decorate that method with any of the following attributes:

[DebuggerStepThrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx) - causes the debugger to step over the method

[DebuggerHidden](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerhiddenattribute.aspx) - hides the method from the debugger (won't even allow breakpoints)

[DebuggerNonUserCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggernonusercodeattribute.aspx) - a combination of the previous two

Answer (score 2):

See if the DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
 HitTestResult result;
 try
 {
    result = this.HitTest( e.X, e.Y, ChartElementType.DataPoint);
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {       
    if(!Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        //This happens, we don't care!
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do the following?

```
 HitTestResult result;
 try
 {
    result = this.HitTest( e.X, e.Y, ChartElementType.DataPoint);
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
 #if !DEBUG
    //This happens, we don't care!
 #endif
 }
```

Comment: This will not change what the function does in release mode. He wants the debugger to skip the exception that the call to .HitTest makes.

Comment: I think he wants to skip it only while developing. If he doesn't want this behavior in release also then why not just delete it?

Comment: I don't think the MSIL generated from this code is will be any different for Debug/Release builds.

Comment: This won't work.. It will still stop at the try / catch. That's what he wants to prevent.

Comment: @0A0D: Are you sure? If HitTest raises and exception it would basically enter an empty catch clause while in debug mode. There is nothing there to handle it or throw it again up the call stack so wouldn't it just *swallow* the exception which is what he wants?

Comment: This does absolutely nothing.

Comment: @InBetween: It will still stop. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to break on all exceptions *except* this one but VS doesn't offer this option.

I would recommend rewriting the HitTest() method so that it handles failures gracefully instead of allowing exceptions to be thrown, for example by validating the input parameters.

*Correction:* 0A0D's answer shows that this is possible and that will work best with API calls or other code you don't have control over.  But when you do, you should consider rewriting it to handle errors gracefully.

Comment: It sounds like HitTest is an API call, as he said he has no control whether is throws an exception.

Comment: The exception is thrown in System.Windows.DataVisualization.Charting.HitTest function.  When the mousemove event is thrown before the chart is painted, this exception will be thrown.  This is from a crappy implementation in the order of eventprocessing from that chart control itself.  I'm not going to waste time ensureing that the chart has a "valid, good" painted status before I attempt the mousemove event.  If the chart hasn't been drawn, I just want to ignore it.

Comment: @CJohnson: A developer who who makes unvalidated assumptions is demonstrating a lack of real world experience. Why do you assume this is laziness? Clearly @greggor has thought about this and reasoned that an empty catch block is the appropriate solution for this case.